# Matrix weight algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to work out how to write an algorithm to calculate the weights across different lists the most efficient way. I have a dict which contains various ids:

```
x["Y"]=[id1,id2,id3...]
x["X"]=[id2,id3....]
x["Z"]=[id3]
.
.
```

I have an associated weight for each of the elements:

```
w["Y"]=10
w["X"]=10
w["Z"]=5
```

Given an input, e.g. `"Y","Z"`, I want to get an output of to give me:

```
(id1,10),(id2,10),(id3,15)
```

`id3` gets 15 because it's in both `x["Y"]` and `x["Z"]`.

Is there a way way I can do this with vector matrixes?

Comment: id2 is in both x["X"] and x["Y"], so should it be (id2, 20) instead?

Comment: no the input is Y and Z so it only looks at all the ids from x["Y"] and x["Z"]. Id2 gets 10 from x["Y"] it's not in x["Z"] so doesn't get any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `itertools` library to group together common terms in a list:

```
import itertools
import operator

a = {'x': [2,3], 'y': [1,2,3], 'z': [3]}
b = {'x': 10, 'y': 10, 'z': 5}

def matrix_weight(letter1,letter2):
    final_list = []
    for i in a[letter1]:
        final_list.append((i, b[letter1]))
    for i in a[letter2]:
        final_list.append((i, b[letter2]))

    # final_list = [(1,10), (2,10), (3,10), (3,5)]
    it = itertools.groupby(final_list, operator.itemgetter(0))
    for key, subiter in it:
        yield key, sum(item[1] for item in subiter)

print list(matrix_weight('y', 'z'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the `id` in strings as in your example, but integer id works similarly.

```
def id_weights(x, w, keys):
    result = {}
    for key in keys:
        for id in x[key]:
            if id not in result:
                result[id] = 0
            result[id] += w[key]
    return [(id, result[id]) for id in sorted(result.keys())]

x = {"Y": ["id1","id2","id3"],
     "X": ["id2", "id3"],
     "Z": ["id3"]}
w = {"Y": 10, "X": 10, "Z": 5}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = ["Y", "Z"]
    print id_weights(x, w, keys)
```

gives

```
[('id1', 10), ('id2', 10), ('id3', 15)]
```